# Insert new value Into SortedLinked List using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list

I implement the following code, it works but it added the new values at the end of linked list Like, [1,2,3,6], value 4 
the results are [1,2,3,6,4] which is wrong 
the correct results is [1,2,3,4,6]

```
# Singly-linked lists are already defined with this interface:
class ListNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.value = x
        self.next = None

def insertValueIntoSortedLinkedList(head, valuetoInsert):

    currentNode = head

    while currentNode is not None:
        if currentNode.next is None:
            currentNode.next = ListNode(valuetoInsert)
            return head
        currentNode = currentNode.next
```

My Question how to modifie the insertValueIntoSortedLinkedList function
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes to `insertValueIntoSortedLinkedList()`. Basically, the error is that you don't compare if the value you're going to insert is smaller than current value (so you always insert the new value to end).

```
# Singly-linked lists are already defined with this interface:
class ListNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.value = x
        self.next = None

def insertValueIntoSortedLinkedList(head, valuetoInsert):
    currentNode = head
    while True:
        # is current value greater than value we are going to insert?
        if currentNode.value > valuetoInsert:
            # yes, create new node with old value
            next_node = ListNode(currentNode.value)
            next_node.next = currentNode.next

            # replace current value with new value (which is lower than old value)
            currentNode.value = valuetoInsert

            # set next node to new node we created previously (with old value)
            currentNode.next = next_node
            # we are done, return
            return

        # we are at the end, so break from while-loop
        if currentNode.next is None:
            break

        currentNode = currentNode.next

    # the valuetoInsert is greater than all values so far, so insert it to the end
    currentNode.next = ListNode(valuetoInsert)

def print_list(head):
    """ Helper method to print the list """
    currentNode = head

    while currentNode is not None:
        print(currentNode.value)
        currentNode = currentNode.next

l = ListNode(1)
insertValueIntoSortedLinkedList(l, 2)
insertValueIntoSortedLinkedList(l, 3)
insertValueIntoSortedLinkedList(l, 6)

insertValueIntoSortedLinkedList(l, 4)  # this inserts value before 6

print_list(l)
```

Prints:

```
1
2
3
4
6
```

Comment: Thank you Andrej Kesely